# Retrieving value from Request URL

Tags: java, url, wicket

I have an URL which will call a method my method in Java. It looks like this:

```
http://www.example.com/method?value=24
```

How can I retrieve value `24` and use it in my called method?

Comment: what framework? Using a servlet? A JSP? Or a `URL` object. What method and how it is called.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am assuming here that you do create the number - the '24' - in your Java code, since you say you are using Wicket.

Thus, as seanizer already said, in 99% of the cases, you do not need to parse the request url to get the value, something like this should be sufficient:

```
public class MyPage extends WebPage {
   public MyPage() {
      // your number is generated somehow
      final int value = 24;

      this.add(new Link<Integer>("myLink") {
         @Override
         public void onClick() {
            // do something with the value
            int newValue = value * 2;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

or - with models - like this

```
public class MyPage extends WebPage {
       public MyPage() {
          // your number is generated somehow
          int value = 24;

          Model<Integer> model = new Model<Integer>(value);

          this.add(new Link<Integer>("myLink", model) {
             @Override
             public void onClick() {
                // your '24'
                Integer value = this.getModelObject();
                // do something with the value
                int newValue = value * 2;
             }
          }
       }
    }
```

If you really, really, REALLY-REALLY do need the parameter from the URL, I guess this is what you want:

```
public class MyPage extends WebPage {
       public MyPage(PageParameters parameters) {
          // your number is generated somehow
          Integer value = parameters.getAsInteger("value");
       }
    }
```

Depending on how you configured your application, you might need to implement the other constructors accordingly.

Good luck.

Answer (score 7):

OK, the way to access a request parameter in wicket is this:

```
final Request request = RequestCycle.get().getRequest();
final String valueAsString = request.getParameter("value");
int value = Integer.parseInt(valueAsString);
```

But usually you don't have to do that, because you pass parameters by using [BookmarkablePageLinks](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/link/BookmarkablePageLink.html) with [PageParameters](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/PageParameters.html) objects and read those objects from the [page constructors](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/WebPage.html#WebPage%28org.apache.wicket.PageParameters%29). Read this page for some material on [Bookmarkable Links in Wicket](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/2008/10/using-wicket-labels-and-links.html).

Comment: thank man, U are awesome. and thanks for the link. This wicket link is very usefull. thanks again.

Comment: In the above script am getting nullpointerException at the 1st line 

RequestCycle.get().getRequest();  

this is my code. 


final Request request = RequestCycle.get().getRequest();
final String value = request.getParameter("value");
logger.info(" value from URL : " + value);

and my URL is http://localhost:8080/method?value="test"

Comment: Is this code inside a wicket component? i.e. is there a current request?

Comment: I can actually invoke one of the method and can able to print a log msg just before the above code.

Comment: Read these about RequestCycle: https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/request-cycle-and-request-cycle-processor.html https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/lifecycle-of-a-wicket-application.html http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/RequestCycle.html

Comment: @salman: OK, you un-accepted my answer, but you didn't answer my questions. How do you test the code: is the web app running or are you using WicketTester? If you just paste it into some main class than of course you don't have a request. (There's usually no request in a Component Constructor, either)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Servlets, you can use

[ServletRequest.getParameter(...)](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.servlet/GetReqParam.html)

If you use JSP, you can use the `request` implicit object

[request.getParameter(...)](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.servlet.jsp/getparam.html)

Comment: sorry dude. I forgot to inform you before that its wicket. But thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
public class ExampleServlet extends HttpServlet {

   /** Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code> methods.
    * @param request servlet request
    * @param response servlet response
    */
   protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
   throws ServletException, IOException {

       String s = request.getParameter("value");
       int value = 0;
       try {
            value = Integer.parseInt(s);
       } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
            nfe.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: True for generic servlet development, false for wicket

Comment: You're right, but at the time I answered he didn't specify that he used a framework.

Comment: I know, and I'd leave your answer in place because it's a valid answer for many scenarios (just not this one)

Comment: sorry guys its my fault i forgot to write the framework.. thanks for the help.. @jeroen Rosenberg

Answer (score 0):

One of:

1. in a bookmarkable page, create constructor with single argument PageParameters and get the value from there: p.getString("value") or p.getInt("value)
2. also page level but if you don't have that constructor or are e.g. in a component: getPage().getPageParameters() and get it from there
3. from any component, getRequest().getParameter("value") (or use Request.get() instead)

There are even more ways of getting it, but these are the most straightforward.